Non-Determinant Algorithms for Parameterized Eigenvalue Problem
Given a specific form of a parametrized eigenvalue problem, namely
$$\mathbb{A}\left(\omega\right)\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0},$$
where $\mathbb{A}(\omega)$ is an $n \times n$ matrix that depends on a parameter $\omega$ which is positive, what are approaches to finding values of $\omega$ such that the above equation is satisfied?
I have been taking the usual approach of setting the determinant of $\mathbb{A}$ and setting it to zero combined with standard root finding algorithms in variation of $\omega$, but the difficulty is that, from how $\mathbb{A}$ is constructed, $\det \mathbb{A}$ is not continuous, as it contains asymptotes. This means, theoretically, asymptotes can be arbitrarily close to determinant zeros making finding these zeros difficult. I have been trying to find other approaches, perhaps through other eigenvalue solution techniques.
This paper provides an approach using a Taylor series method, but I fear that the discontinuities in the determinant make this approach unusable.
Are there other approaches to solving this type of problem?

Is $x$ fixed? If so, this is a pretty straightforward application of numerical continuation, which avoids the determinant entirely

I realize now I wasn’t clear in that regard. The eigenvector is not fixed and depends on the parameter.

I see. "Numerical continuation of eigenvalue problems/null space" may be a good starting point to find relevant literature
